# PHP will not report errors

Tags: php, error-handling, apache2

I feel this is weird but I cannot seem to get php to report errors.

I am making a class to check and format some results outside of a CMS to allow greater filter ability without having to create a custom plugin (due to time constraints).

I am including these 2 lines at the top of the page.

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

I have toggled each and tried using both, no effect. My php.ini shows display_errors as being on and same with html_errors. error_reporting is set to 1.

For the older code I have it works, and the error reporting shows notices and errors. Though in some cases I did run into the same problem, though the issue was due to setting a variable outside of a function makes it not able to be called within the function without making it a function parameter. This is why I decided to switch to a class to avoid this problem.

I am trying to make a simple class to do this and output the result as JSON. My php is not perfect but if I at least get an error I can easily diagnose what went wrong. In this case I cannot get php to even show an echo, let alone any data/errors. All i get is a pure white page. Here is the full code I am using, it is a mess as I am in the process up updating it.

```
class k2JSON {
    private $limit = '';
    private $featured = '';
    private $prefix = 'base_';
    private $filter_query = '';
    private $types = array();
    private $dates = array();
    private $build = array();
    private $db_arr = array(
        'name' => 'westerner_days',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'rem',
        'pass' => '#w1n1nng'
    );
    function __construct(){
        echo 'called constructor <br />';
        if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
            $this->limit = ' LIMIT '.$_GET['limit'];
        }
        if(isset($_GET['featured'])){
            $this->featured = " AND `featured`='".$_GET['featured']."'";
        }
        $this->db = new mysqli(
            $db_arr['host'], 
            $db_arr['user'], 
            $db_arr['pass'], 
            $db_arr['name']
        );
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $this->checkFilter();
        $this->checkDates();
        $this->checkExtra();
    };
    private function checkFilter(){
        if(isset($_GET['filter'])){
            switch($_GET['filter']){
                case 'entertainment':
                    $this->filter_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_items` WHERE `catid` IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11){$this->featured} AND `trash`='0'".$this->limit;
                    break;
                case 'midway':
                    $this->filter_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_items` WHERE `catid` IN (12,13,14){$this->featured} AND `trash`='0'".$this->limit;
                    break;
                case 'off-site':
                    $this->filter_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_items` WHERE `catid` IN (15,16,17,18){$this->featured} AND `trash`='0'".$this->limit;
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->filter_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_items` WHERE `catid` IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18){$this->featured} AND `trash`='0'".$this->limit;
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            $this->filter_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_items` WHERE `catid` IN (5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18){$this->featured} AND `trash`='0'".$this->limit;
        }
        $this->filter_result = $this->db->query($this->filter_query) or die($this->db->error.__LINE__);
    };
    private function checkDates(){
        $this->date_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_extra_fields` WHERE `id` IN (2,14,11) AND `published`='1'";
        $this->date_result = $this->db->query($this->date_query) or die($this->db->error.__LINE__);
        while($row = $this->date_result->fetch_assoc()){
            $this->dates[$row['id']] = json_decode($row['value']);
        }
    };
    private function checkExtra(){
        $this->extra_query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->prefix}k2_extra_fields` WHERE `published`='1'";
        $this->extra_result = $this->db->query($this->extra_query) or die($this->db->error.__LINE__);
        while($row = $this->extra_result->fetch_assoc()){
            $this->types[$row['id']] = json_decode($row['value']);
        }
    };
    private function buildOutput($data){
        $compile = array();
        $compile['extra']= array();
        $compile['title'] = $data['title'];
        $compile['featured'] = $data['featured'];
        $compile['published'] = $data['published'];
        $compile['desc'] = $data['introtext'];
        $compile['link'] = 'http://'.
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
            dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'/'.
            (isset($_GET['filter'])?
                $_GET['filter']:
                in_array($data['catid'],[5,6,7,8,9,10,11])?
                    'entertainment':
                    in_array($data['catid'],[12,13,14])?
                        'midway':
                        in_array($data['catid'],[15,16,17,18])?
                            'off-site':
                            ''
            ).'/view/item/'.$data['id'].'-'.$data['alias'];
        $compile['type'] = $data['catid'];
        $compile['image'] = array(
            'xsmall' => '/media/k2/items/cache/'.md5('Image'.$data['id']).'_XS.jpg',
            'small' => '/media/k2/items/cache/'.md5('Image'.$data['id']).'_S.jpg',
            'medium' => '/media/k2/items/cache/'.md5('Image'.$data['id']).'_M.jpg',
            'large' => '/media/k2/items/cache/'.md5('Image'.$data['id']).'_L.jpg',
            'xlarge' => '/media/k2/items/cache/'.md5('Image'.$data['id']).'_XL.jpg',
        );
        $extra = json_decode($data['extra_fields']);
        foreach($extra as $key=>$value){
            switch($extra[$key]->id){
                case 2:
                    if(is_array($extra[$key]->value)){
                        $return_array = array();
                        foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                            if($this->dates['2'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name!=null){
                                $return_array[]=$this->dates['2'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name;
                            }
                        }
                        $compile['date'] = $return_array;
                    }else{
                        $compile['date'] = $this->dates['2'][$extra[$key]->value-1]->name;
                    }
                    break;
                case 14:
                    if(is_array($extra[$key]->value)){
                        $return_array = array();
                        foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                            if($dates['14'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name!=null){
                                $return_array[]=$this->dates['14'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name;
                            }
                        }
                        $compile['date'] = $return_array;
                    }else{
                        $compile['date'] = $this->dates['14'][$extra[$key]->value-1]->name;
                    }
                    break;
                case 11:
                    if(is_array($extra[$key]->value)){
                        $return_array = array();
                        foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                            if($dates['11'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name!=null){
                                $return_array[]=$this->dates['11'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name;
                            }
                        }
                        $compile['date'] = $return_array;
                    }else{
                        $compile['date'] = $this->dates['11'][$extra[$key]->value-1]->name;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
                case 15:
                    if(is_array($extra[$key]->value)){
                        $return_array = array();
                        foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                            $return_array[]=$this->types['15'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]]->name;
                        }
                        $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $return_array;
                    }else{
                        $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $this->types['15'][$extra[$key]->value]->name;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if(is_array($extra[$key]->value)){
                        $return_array = array();
                        foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                            $return_array[]=$this->types['1'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]]->name;
                        }
                        $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $return_array;
                    }else{
                        $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $this->types['1'][$extra[$key]->value]->name;
                    }
                    break;
                case 7:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
                case 18:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
                case 16:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    $compile['extra'][$extra[$key]->id] = $extra[$key]->value;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $compile;
    };
    public function parse(){
        if($this->filter_result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $this->filter_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if(isset($_GET['date'])){ //date but could have type
                    $extra = json_decode($row['extra_fields']);
                    foreach($extra as $key=>$value){
                        if($extra[$key]->id==2||$extra[$key]->id==14||$extra[$key]->id==11){ //find date extrafield
                            $check_array = array();
                            foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                                $check_array[]=$dates['2'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name;
                            }
                            foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                                $check_array[]=$dates['14'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name;
                            }
                            foreach($extra[$key]->value as $key2=>$value2){
                                $check_array[]=$dates['11'][$extra[$key]->value[$key2]-1]->name;
                            }
                            $compile['date'] = $check_array;
                            if(in_array($_GET['date'],$check_array)){
                                if(isset($_GET['type'])){ //type is set
                                    if($row['catid']==$_GET['type']){
                                        $this->build[]=$this->buildOutput($row);
                                    }
                                }else{ //type is not set, output all values.
                                    $bthis->build[]=$this->buildOutput($row);
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }else if(isset($_GET['type'])){ //only type
                    if($row['catid']==$_GET['type']){
                        $this->build[]=$this->buildOutput($row);
                    }
                }else{ //no filters
                    $this->build[]=$this->buildOutput($row);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    public function outputResult(){
        print_r($this->build);
        echo json_encode($this->build);
    };
};
echo 'init <br />';
$json = new k2JSON();
$json->parse();
$json->outputResult();
```

I know there is probably some very obvious mistakes. But without php errors I cannot narrow it down. I hope that to someone with more experience with php this problem has an obvious fix.

Comment: When you say you are including those lines I assume you are removing the // from the start of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you are getting errors?

try this also:

```
@ini_set('error_reporting', 'true');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

your functions may be wrong you write functions like

```
public function something() {}; <==
```

write them like

```
public function something() {}
```

doesnt solve your error problem, but at least a note

Comment: I have tried that and I still just get a white page. and yes, becuase otherwise my "echo" statement should show something right?

Comment: weird because I am getting errors when I run this, without any ini_set or error_reporting code...
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in G:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 37

Comment: Yea it is baffling me, I feel it might be something apache. though my phpinfo shows what I see as proper error settings.

Comment: also make sure the display_errors isnt listed more then 1 times in the php.ini, the second 1 will override the first one

Comment: but the one listed in phpinfo should be what php is seeing as the proper one right? or does it manually read the php.ini? Also I will fix that, thank you it is just a habit as I am a javascript programmer mainly.

Comment: what server are you using? xampp? wampp? or something else?

Comment: did you also restart apache when you made the changes ?

Comment: I have not needed to change the php.ini yet to need to, I am looking through things but the php .ini is default, witch means a lot of scrolling to look at it properly... I will jump into looking through it now.

Comment: I got an error!!!!!!! YAY. seems that the ini set and such does not override the php.ini setting for parse errors only. by manually telling to to not avoid parse errors it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ';' after methods brackets inside the class methods, and tell us if it works.

Comment: I have deleted all the ones I can see, still a white page.

Comment: there are more errors then this 1 also  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in G:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 85

Comment: change the array declaration, from 5.4 way to the old way (is your php server 5.4?): i.e. in line 85 [5,6,7,..] to array(5,6,7,...)

Answer (score 0):

quit the "//" in

> //error_reporting(E_ALL);
>
> //ini_set('display_errors', '1');

and remove the ";" after of functions declarations

Comment: I had stated that I toggled them, by that i meant I uncommented them and commented them in different variations to test. As for the ';' after functions, that was not the root problem in the end. It was php not allowing a page to override the error_reporting. The reason I used the ';' in the first place is that I am a JavaScript programmer mainly, and it is good practice to avoid problems with compressing the code later on.